# Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, name, value = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, : 189 elements in value to replace 188 elements

Tags: r

I need help with following: I get an error:

> Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, name, value = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
> 3L, :  189 elements in value to replace 188 elements

The error happened when running the last line: `colData(sce)$conds <- factor(conds$group)`

Here is the code line:

```
myxp <- read.table("/Users/Desktop/normalized.csv",
                   header = TRUE,row.names = "pathway",sep = ",")

conds <- read.table("/Users/Desktop/metadata.tsv",
                    header = TRUE,row.names = "SampleID",sep = ",")

myxp <- as.matrix(myxp)

sce <- SingleCellExperiment(assays = List(counts = myxp))
colData(sce)$conds <- factor(conds$group)
```